# How to download the dataURL string as image in c#

Tags: c#, image, canvas, export

Hi I need to export HTML5 Canvas as Image in C# - server side (code behind). I am working in MVC and ASP platforms.

I converted canvas to dataURL in script and passed it to controller. Now want to convert this to image.

My code in c# page is

```
public void ExportAsImage(string DataURL)
    {

    }
```

DataURL value looks like below

> "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+AAAAJYCAYAAADiyYzRAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAAC......
>   " goes on.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Image ExportAsImage(string DataURL)
{
    Image i = new Bitmap(250, 20);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(i);
    g.DrawString(DataURL, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0,0));
    g.Dispose();

    return i;
}
   pictureBox.Image = ExportAsImage("http://example.com");
```